# Can't build shared library of Osmand

Tags: android-ndk, build-process

I followed the steps  as exactly as [installDevelopmentEnvironment](https://code.google.com/p/osmand/wiki/InstallDevelopmentEnvironment) said.

After "repo sync",I run the script ndk-build.sh under android/OsmAnd directory.
I have added ANDROID_SDK, ANDROID_NDK, JAVA_HOME in my PATH environment var.My OS is Centos 6.The edition of my ndk is r8.

After the script finished,I checked the shared library files. Library files about QT are just built right,such as libQt5Core.so while library files about Osmand, such as libOsmAndCore.so , are not built.

I checked the output log ,at last it said:

> Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in jni/../../../core/Android.mk for module OsmAndCore
>   Android NDK:   ./src/Location.cpp_ ./src/OsmAndApplication.cpp_ ./src/PlatformAPI.cpp_
>   Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in jni/../../../core/Android.mk for module OsmAndCore
>   Android NDK:   ./src/Location.cpp_ ./src/OsmAndApplication.cpp_ ./src/PlatformAPI.cpp_
>   Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in jni/../../../core/Android.mk for module OsmAndCore_neon
>   Android NDK:   ./src/Location.cpp_ ./src/OsmAndApplication.cpp_ ./src/PlatformAPI.cpp_
>   Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in jni/../../../core/Android.mk for module OsmAndCore
>   Android NDK:   ./src/Location.cpp_ ./src/OsmAndApplication.cpp_ ./src/PlatformAPI.cpp_
>   Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in jni/../../../core/Android.mk for module OsmAndCore
>   Android NDK:   ./src/Location.cpp_ ./src/OsmAndApplication.cpp_ ./src/PlatformAPI.cpp_
>   make: *** No rule to make target `jni/../../../core/externals/protobuf/./upstream.patched/src/google/protobuf/extension_set.cc', needed by`obj/local/armeabi/objs/osmand_protobuf/./upstream.patched/src/google/protobuf/extension_set.o'.  Stop.
>   make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>   Compile++ thumb  : OsmAndCore <= java_wrap.cpp

I didn't change any file in the project.
I read Android.mk file above and can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Here is the Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

ifeq ($(OSMAND_BUILDING_NEON_LIBRARY),true)
    QT := $(LOCAL_PATH)/externals/qtbase-android/upstream.patched.$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)-neon
else
    QT := $(LOCAL_PATH)/externals/qtbase-android/upstream.patched.$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
endif
OSMAND_PROTOBUF := $(LOCAL_PATH)/externals/protobuf/upstream.patched
OSMAND_SKIA_ROOT := $(LOCAL_PATH)/externals/skia
OSMAND_SKIA := $(LOCAL_PATH)/externals/skia/upstream.patched
OSMAND_EXPAT := $(LOCAL_PATH)/externals/expat/upstream.patched
OSMAND_CORE_RELATIVE := .
OSMAND_CORE := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(OSMAND_CORE_RELATIVE)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(QT)/include \
    $(QT)/include/QtCore \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/src \
    $(OSMAND_PROTOBUF)/src \
    $(OSMAND_SKIA_ROOT) \
    $(OSMAND_SKIA) \
    $(OSMAND_EXPAT)/lib \
    $(OSMAND_SKIA)/include/core \
    $(OSMAND_SKIA)/include/config \
    $(OSMAND_SKIA)/include/effects \
    $(OSMAND_SKIA)/include/images \
    $(OSMAND_SKIA)/include/ports \
    $(OSMAND_SKIA)/include/utils \
    $(OSMAND_SKIA)/include/utils/android \
    $(OSMAND_SKIA)/src/core \
    $(OSMAND_CORE)/include \
    $(OSMAND_CORE)/src \
    $(OSMAND_CORE)/protos \
    $(OSMAND_CORE)/native/include \
    $(OSMAND_CORE)/native/src

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cc .cpp
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(OSMAND_CORE)/src/*.c*)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    $(SRC_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%) \
    $(OSMAND_CORE_RELATIVE)/native/src/ElapsedTimer.cpp \
    $(OSMAND_CORE_RELATIVE)/native/src/common.cpp \
    $(OSMAND_CORE_RELATIVE)/native/src/mapObjects.cpp \
    $(OSMAND_CORE_RELATIVE)/native/src/multipolygons.cpp \
    $(OSMAND_CORE_RELATIVE)/native/src/renderRules.cpp \
    $(OSMAND_CORE_RELATIVE)/native/src/rendering.cpp \
    $(OSMAND_CORE_RELATIVE)/native/src/binaryRead.cpp \
    $(OSMAND_CORE_RELATIVE)/native/src/binaryRoutePlanner.cpp \
    $(OSMAND_CORE_RELATIVE)/native/src/proto/osmand_index.pb.cc \
    $(OSMAND_CORE_RELATIVE)/native/src/java_wrap.cpp

ifdef OSMAND_PROFILE_NATIVE_OPERATIONS
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += \
        -DOSMAND_NATIVE_PROFILING
endif

# Name of the local module
ifneq ($(OSMAND_BUILDING_NEON_LIBRARY),true)
    LOCAL_MODULE := OsmAndCore
else
    LOCAL_MODULE := OsmAndCore_neon
    LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
endif

LOCAL_CFLAGS := \
    -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI \
    -DSK_BUILD_FOR_ANDROID \
    -DSK_BUILD_FOR_ANDROID_NDK \
    -DSK_ALLOW_STATIC_GLOBAL_INITIALIZERS=0 \
    -DSK_RELEASE \
    -DSK_CPU_LENDIAN \
    -DGR_RELEASE=1 \
    -DANDROID_BUILD \
    -fPIC

ifeq ($(LOCAL_ARM_NEON),true)
    OSMAND_BINARY_SUFFIX := _neon
else
    OSMAND_BINARY_SUFFIX :=
endif

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
    osmand_protobuf$(OSMAND_BINARY_SUFFIX) \
    osmand_jpeg$(OSMAND_BINARY_SUFFIX) \
    osmand_ft2$(OSMAND_BINARY_SUFFIX) \
    osmand_png$(OSMAND_BINARY_SUFFIX) \
    osmand_gif$(OSMAND_BINARY_SUFFIX) \
    osmand_expat$(OSMAND_BINARY_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := osmand_skia$(OSMAND_BINARY_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
    Qt5Core$(OSMAND_BINARY_SUFFIX)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?